# What will registering an apple device a developer device do to it?

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program, ipad-2, ios7

I have an iPad 2 and I need a device to test my ios app on. I was wondering if their are any consequences to registering a device to be a developer device. For example, can I still use it as a regular device when I am not developing on it? Will I be able to use it regularly if I put iOS 7 on it? I need to start working on this project, so if anyone knows, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only install a beta version of iOS on a device dedicated to development. Once you install the beta iOS, you may find many apps no longer work. If you depend on the device for everyday use, do not install a beta on it. But otherwise, using it for non-beta development is perfectly safe.

Comment: ok. I won't put ios 7 on it then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can still use it as a regular device. All registering does is enable the Developer section in Settings, allow you to install iOS beta releases, debug builds directly from Xcode, and ad hoc app builds.

Also to elaborate on the Developer section in the Settings app, as of iOS 6 and above, that gives you access to the network link conditioner so you can simulate for instance 3G or EDGE speeds when on Wifi. Very useful.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying it out now. Will upvote and approve your answer once I get it working

Comment: Also, registering that device will allow you to test/debug your code on a real device, including setting breakpoints etc.

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention that it allows installs directly from Xcode as well of course. I'll update my answer for completeness sake.